# Undo Operation In CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I want to undo my last operation.I am using this code. But I am unable to do this. Please help .Any help would be apperciated

Firstly I am saving record

```
@IBAction func save(sender: AnyObject) {
    let appDelegate =
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate        

    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Person",
        inManagedObjectContext:managedContext)
    entity!.uniquenessConstraints = [["name"]]
    let person = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!,
        insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

    //3
    person.setValue(first.text, forKey: "name")
    person.setValue(second.text, forKey: "age")

    //4
    do {
        try managedContext.save()
        //5
        people.append(person)

    } catch let error as NSError  {
        print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }        
}
```

Then i Want to redo

```
  let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate   
  appDelegate.managedObjectContext.undo()
```

Answer (score 0):

`NSManagedObjectContext` need an undo manger to enable undo operations. On iOS, by default (for performance reasons), it doesn't have one.

Even if it *did* (you can create and assign one) your code wouldn't work - undo reverses the latest uncommitted changes. In your example you have saved the context - there's no built-in undo support for that.

Given the modal nature of most edit / insert operations on iOS it's usually easier to create a new context to use as an editing scratchpad and either throw that away (if the user hits dismiss or cancel) or save it (if the user hits save or done or whatever).

Comment: Thanks Sir... Please send some code snippet. I am new in iOS

Comment: For which part?

Comment: For exactly save operation

Comment: I'm not sure a code snippet is going to help you here. What is it that you are trying to do?

Comment: Sir First I am insert record. Then some condition i want to undo my operation. I am getting sucess in save. But failure in undo operation

Comment: Yes, and as I said, once you've saved, there is no built in undo support, even if you add an undo manager. You'd have to delete the record manually.

Comment: Okay Sir... got your point . for which purpose we have used appDelegate.managedObjectContext.undo()

Comment: Don't save for every insert. Save only when needed. That way you can undo.